# Always have two tab rows in WPF TabControl

Tags: wpf

I have a TabControl in a WPF application and sometimes it has one tab row and other times it has two tab rows depending on the width of the parent control. This is certainly the expected behavior for a TabControl.

However I want there to always be two tab rows. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

[image: TabControls]

```
                    <TabControl x:Name="StackOverflowTabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TabItem>
                        <TabItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Hey" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                        </TabItem.Header>
                        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Label Content="Hey" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </TabItem>

                    <TabItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <TabItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Blah" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                        </TabItem.Header>
                        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <Label Content="Hey 2" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </TabItem>

                    <TabItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <TabItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Whatever" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                        </TabItem.Header>
                        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <Label Content="Whatever" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </TabItem>

                    <TabItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <TabItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Info" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                        </TabItem.Header>
                        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <Label Content="Under Construction" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </TabItem>

                    <TabItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  >
                        <TabItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Something" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                        </TabItem.Header>
                        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <Label Content="Hey" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </TabItem>

                    <TabItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <TabItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Nothing" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                        </TabItem.Header>
                        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <Label Content="Hey 3" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </TabItem>

                    <TabItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <TabItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Forms" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                        </TabItem.Header>
                        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <Label Content="Under Construction" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </TabItem>

                </TabControl>
```

Comment: If you have a fixed layout (or at least a maximum parent size), you could simply assign an appropriate `MinWidth` to the various tab headers until you get the arrangement you desire.  This likely isn't flexible enough for you, but it's worth mentioning :).

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I'll do some thinking about it.

Comment: Mike's suggestion is probably best if you indeed have a fixed layout. However, this means when a user reduces width enough, you'll get 3 rows instead of 2... which violates your requirement of "I want two rows all the time". What does "all the time mean" really? What happens when two rows is not enough to fit all the tabs given your containing view's width? Is the behavior you want really "I want a minimum of two rows no matter how much space I have, and then additional rows as necessary"?

Comment: @Rowbear thanks for your help. There are some things I left out of the problem description. 1) It will not be possible for the user to reduce the width to drop it to 3 rows. 2) To keep things simple I didn't explain the reason for a fixed number of rows. When there is one row AND the width is almost at the point where the second row is wrapped AND one or more of the tabs has content with a vertical scroll bar, then clicking on that tab will suddenly cause the second row to appear. This behavior is annoying the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the TabControl and select EditTemplate->Edit a Copy to get a copy of the template. Then find the TabPanel in the template and add HorizontalAlignment="Left" and MaxWidth=x, where x is the width at which you want the tab items to go to the next line.
Below is an example with a width of 200.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Background" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Border" Color="#ACACAC"/>
    <Style x:Key="TabControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TabPanel x:Name="headerPanel" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="4,0,0,2" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1" MaxWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <Border x:Name="contentPanel" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,0,2,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,2,0,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0,2,2,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try.

Comment: This works great. Hopefully the users will like this solution as well.